# How to add a specific point on a curve in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to add a point to my curve in plotly when x equals a specified value. I know I can use add_trace, but the issue here is I don't know what the y value would be therefore cannot specify it. How would I approach this?

Comment: y[which.max(x)] ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the equation of the curve you are plotting. Suppose your equation looks like this `f1 = function(x) -.23*x^5+1.33*x^3-2.6*x^2+48.7*x+123.89e3*cos(x)`.

The next step is very simple

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 = function(x) -.23*x^5+1.33*x^3-2.6*x^2+48.7*x+123.89e3*cos(x)

ggplot(tibble(x=0, y=0), aes(x, y))+
  stat_function(fun = f1) + xlim(-25,25)+
  geom_point(data=tibble(x=12, y=f1(x)), color = "red", size = 3)+
  geom_point(data=tibble(x=-8, y=f1(x)), color = "blue", size = 3)+
  geom_point(data=tibble(x=0, y=f1(x)), color = "green", size = 3)
```

[image]

As you can see, I added three different points there. But you can also add more points. E.g. like this:

```
ggplot(tibble(x=0, y=0), aes(x, y))+
  stat_function(fun = f1) + xlim(-25,25)+
  geom_point(data=tibble(x = runif(7, -25, 25), y = f1(x)), color = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]